# How can I use an AngularJS filter to format a number to have leading zeros?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I checked the [documentation](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.filter:number). What I would like is for my numbers to have four digits and leading zeros.

```
22 to 0022
1  to 0001
```

Can someone help and tell me if this is possible with the number or another kind of filter?

Comment: Why is there no accepted answer for this question? Rectify.

Answer (score 113):

No filter required, Just use an expression in your html

```
{{("00000"+1).slice(-6)}}      // '000001'

{{("00000"+123456).slice(-6)}} // '123456'
```

Comment: It's all fun and games until the input is more than 6 digits

Answer (score 64):

Let's say you have a module called `myModule` in your app `myApp`:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myModule']);
```

Define your filter in in this module:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .filter('numberFixedLen', function () {
        return function (n, len) {
            var num = parseInt(n, 10);
            len = parseInt(len, 10);
            if (isNaN(num) || isNaN(len)) {
                return n;
            }
            num = ''+num;
            while (num.length < len) {
                num = '0'+num;
            }
            return num;
        };
    });
```

Use your filter in markup:

```
{{myValue | numberFixedLen:4}}
```

Comment: in the case of this particular function, numberFixedLen, wouldn't it be better to put it either in the global scope or into a utility class, since it is basically a global-useful utility function ... ?

Comment: This solution would work fine for integers, but decimals wouldn't be counted correctly

Answer (score 47):

Keeping it minimal... (works with both strings & numbers) Do some validation if you have to (isNumber, NaN)

```
// 1e8 is enough for working with 8 digits (100000000)
// in your case 1e4 (aka 10000) should do it
app.filter('numberFixedLen', function () {
    return function(a,b){
        return(1e4+""+a).slice(-b);
    };
});
```

If you want it even smaller and the browser supports arrow function or you are using babel/traceur then it could be reduced to:

```
app.filter('numberFixedLen', () => (a, b) => (1e4 + "" + a).slice(-b))
```

html:

```
{{ myValue | numberFixedLen:4 }}
```

---

**Note** This has less flexibility and this will only work for numbers lower then 10000 if it's a bigger number you would have to increase both `4` and `1e4` or use any other dynamic solution.
This was intended to do as little as possible as fast as possible.

It is intentionally the same thing as doing:

```
("10000"+1234567).slice(-4) // "4567"
("10000"+1234567).slice(-9) // "001234567"
```

---

**Update** You could also use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) (but it doesn't work in IE)

```js
// app.filter('numberFixedLen', () => (a, b) => ("" + a).padStart(b, 0))

console.log("1234567".padStart(4, 0)) // "1234567"
console.log("1234567".padStart(9, 0)) // "001234567"
```

Comment: While this answer does have less flexibility, it is quite a bit faster.

Comment: Beautifully simple, with smart usage of slice() with negative argument which is actually quite readable even though I'd never seen it before.

Comment: This worked great! I just made a slight modification to only convert non-numbers (OL01 needs to show as such):

`app.filter('numberFixedLen', function () {
    return function(a,b){
     if (isNaN(a)) {
      return a
     } else {
            return(1e4+a+"").slice(-b);
     }
    };
});`

Comment: The slice way is great

Answer (score 8):

Minimum code with [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string)'s [padding](http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/#pad-str-length-padstr-type-gt-string) function and the [angular-underscore-string filter](https://github.com/tlvince/angular-underscore-string):

[working demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/y9L920fw/)

---

> angular string input -> angular-underscore-string filter -> underscore.string

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PadController">
   <div ng-repeat="num in nums">{{ num | s: 'pad':[4, '0'] }}</div>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('app', ['underscore.string']).controller('PadController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
});

// 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

The `s` variable refers to the string library. In older versions you might have to substitute it for "_.str", ie. `{{ num | _.str: 'pad':[4, '0'] }}`

Comment: I got this working with: bower install angular-underscore-string --save && bower install underscore.string -save (don't forget to include the js files bower_components/underscore.string/dist/underscore.string.min.js  and bower_components/angular-underscore-string/underscore.string.min.js

Answer (score 6):

If you are dealing exclusively with "0" padding and don't mind tailoring your filters by use case, I'd go with something similar to Endless's answer for speed but would recommend you make sure the number isn't already long enough with something like:

```
app.filter('minLength', function () {
    return function(input,len){
        input = input.toString();
        if(input.length >= len) return input;
        else return("000000"+input).slice(-len);
    }
});
```

As this will not only save it from trimming numbers or strings that already satisfy the minimum length which is important to avoid weird stuff like:

```
{{ 0.23415336 | minLength:4 }} //Returns "0.23415336" instead of "5336" like in Endless's code
```

But by using "000000" instead of a number like 1e6 you avoid both changing the actual value of the input (by not adding 1000000 to it) and avoid the need to implicitly convert the number to a string thereby saving a computational step considering the input would already be a converted to a string to avoid the clipping issue mentioned above.

If you want a system that doesn't need any use-case testing that's both faster and more flexible than bguiz's solution I use a filter like:

```
app.filter('minLength', function(){
  return function(input, len, pad){
    input = input.toString(); 
    if(input.length >= len) return input;
    else{
      pad = (pad || 0).toString(); 
      return new Array(1 + len - input.length).join(pad) + input;
    }
  };
});
```

This allows you to do the standard:

```
{{ 22 | minLength:4 }} //Returns "0022"
```

But also gives you the option to add non-zero padding options like:

```
{{ 22 | minLength:4:"-" }} //Returns "--22"
```

and you can enforce wacky stuff with numbers or strings like:

```
{{ "aa" | minLength:4:"&nbsp;" }} //Returns "  aa"
```

Plus, if the input is already longer than your desired length, the filter will just pop it back out without any trimming:

```
{{ 1234567 | minLength:4 }} //Returns "1234567"
```

You also avoid the need to add validation for `len` because when you call the filter without a `len` argument, angular will throw a `RangeError` in your console at the line where you try to create an array of length `null` making it simple to debug.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use pure JavaScript such as

```
('00000'+refCounter).substr(-5,5)
```

for padding with 5 zeros the value of **refCounter**.

NOTE: Make sure to check that **refCounter** is not **undefined**, otherwise you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Pls use the below filter modify if required for some modifications

```
  app.filter('customNo', function () {
            return function (input) {
                var n = input;
                return (n < 10) ? '000' + n : (n < 100) ? '00' + n : (n < 1000) ? '0' + n : '' + n;
            }
        });


<span>{{number|customNo}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

```
// Formats a number to be at least minNumberOfDigits by adding leading zeros
app.filter('LeadingZerosFilter', function() {
  return function(input, minNumberOfDigits) {
    minNumberOfDigits = minNumberOfDigits || 2;
    input = input + '';
    var zeros = new Array(minNumberOfDigits - input.length + 1).join('0');
    return zeros + input;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest would be to create your own filter in angular and use it. There's already a few answers for this but personally I find this easiest to read. Create a array by the length of zeros needed then join the array with zero.

```
myApp.filter('customNumber', function(){
    return function(input, size) {
        var zero = (size ? size : 4) - input.toString().length + 1;
        return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + input;
    }
});
```

Use it like:

```
{{myValue | customNumber}}
```

I also made it so you can specify leading zeros as a parameter:

```
{{myValue | customNumber:5}}
```

Demo:
http://www.bootply.com/d7SbUz57o8

Comment: I think the original question was looking for leading zeros though, and not decimal places.

Comment: +1 @Joel ! I was creating the solution for setting of decimals and I was too quick to read this question. I've fixed my answer now for leading zeros instead of setting the number of decimals. It differs some from the other answers and I find it more readable. Also included a demo that no others have.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Angular 1.x variant of the directive in TypeScript which would handle both integers and decimals. Everything is considered 'type safe' thanks to TS.

```
adminApp.filter("zeroPadNumber",
    () => (num: number, len: number): string => {
        if (isNaN(num) || isNaN(len)) {
            return `${num}`;
        }
        if (`${num}`.indexOf(".") > -1) {
            var parts = `${num}`.split(".");
            var outDec = parts[0]; // read the before decimal
            while (outDec.length < len) {
                outDec = `0${outDec}`;
            }
            return outDec + parts[1]; // reappend the after decimal
        } else {
            var outInt = `${num}`;
            while (outInt.length < len) {
                outInt = `0${outInt}`;
            }
            return outInt;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've extended [@bguiz's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648014/how-can-i-use-an-angularjs-filter-to-format-a-number-to-have-leading-zeros/48943202#17648547) answer to be able to handle arrays, which was my requirement for using the filter on `ng-options`:

```
app.filter('numberFixedLen', function () {
  return function (p, len) {
    function toFixedLength(n, len) {
      var num = parseInt(n, 10);

      len = parseInt(len, 10);

      if (isNaN(num) || isNaN(len)) {
        return n;
      }

      num = '' + num;

      while (num.length < len) {
        num = '0' + num;
      }

      return num;
    }

    if (p.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        p[i] = toFixedLength(p[i], len);
      }
    } else {
      p = toFixedLength(p, len);
    }

    return p;
  };
});
```

Answer (score -2):

**Example code:**

```
{{ (value > 9 ? (value > 99 ? (value > 999 ? value : '0'+value) : '00'+value) : '000'+value) }}
```

Comment: Can you add documentation/explanation?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!