# How to input hours and minute in angular js ?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is code

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="12" step="1" ng-model="input.hours" required>
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="60" step="5" ng-model="input.minute" required>
```

This is browser preview

[image]

I need to input hours as **08** and minutes **05** But visible **8** and **5**. 
How can do that?

If not clear, comment. Hope answer soon.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `<input type=time>`?

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer if any of them helped you out.

Comment: @Blindy maybe because it is not supported in Safari or Internet Explorer 12 and earlier versions

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ng-change` to insert a `0` before the value each time it changes:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="12" step="1" ng-model="input.hours" required ng-change="onChange(input.hours)">
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="60" step="5" ng-model="input.minute" required ng-change="onChange(input.minute)>

$scope.onChange = function(val) {

  if (val < 10) {
    val = '0' + val;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create a filter to add '0' before number if needed

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17648547/274500