# Format float/double with Angular

Tags: angularjs

This may be a dumb question but I'm very new at Angular. How can I format a float/double to only show two decimals after the separator.

```
 <input type="text" name="whatever" value="{{model.Rate}}" />
```

I saw some [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648014/how-can-i-use-an-angularjs-filter-to-format-a-number-to-have-leading-zeros) in SO but I believe that such a basic operation can be done in a simpler way.

Comment: A double quote end is missing for the value attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angulars has some built-in filter to do that.

[Angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

In your case this should be something like this :

```
value="{{ number_expression | number : 2}}"
```

Comment: Is this outdated for Angular 8? I'm getting an error message `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'digitsInfo.match is not a function' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'`

Comment: For angular 8 use. 
{{ number_expression | number: '1.2-2' }}.
At Least one digit before decimal and 2 max decimal point.

Comment: tiagorockman's example worked for me. In my case, i used "number: '.2'"

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" value="{{model.Rate.toFixed(2)}} />
```

assuming `Rate` is of type `number`

[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string, and always pads with zeros, so `0.toFixed(2) === "0.00"`

Comment: This solution worked for me. User574..'s solution broke my app. So in my case, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

For angular 8 use: 
{{ number_expression | number: '1.2-2' }}.
At Least one digit before decimal and 2 max decimal point.