# How can i append 0 for 1 to 9 using Angular JS inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I need 01, 02 ,03 ..10 instead of 1,2,3,..10 using angular js ,I used ${index+1} for getting the index number, while i need to append 0 for 1 to 9 .

Comment: try this  `0{{$index+1}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648014/how-can-i-use-an-angularjs-filter-to-format-a-number-to-have-leading-zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple...

Here is the code for this, just replace your code with this.

```
{{$index+1 < 10 ? '0' : ''}}{{$index+1}}
```

So this will display like 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11,.. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 
})
.filter('num',function(){
  return function(num){
    if(num.toString().length > 1){
    return num;
    }else{
    return "0"+num;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<div ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
   {{$index | num}}
</div>

</div>
```