# Angular JS: preserve leading zeros for a number

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, numbers

I want to preserve the leading zeros for a number but as usual it trims them.
I tried

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

But this allows text input which breaks my case.

Please help!!!

Comment: Can you please post some code or create a plunkr or fiddle

Comment: Take a look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648014/how-can-i-use-an-angularjs-filter-to-format-a-number-to-have-leading-zeros)

Comment: You can use input type as number and set maxlength and minlength to ensure its a phone number of valid length

Comment: @PRANSHUMIDHA But i am afraid this isn't a phone number. Its just a number which requires to preserve the leading zeros.

Comment: Could you set the input as `text` and retain your pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `input type="text"`, use the `ng-pattern` to validate your expressions and then use `ng-message` to validate your field and display errors.

This won't remove your lead 0s.

So your HTML will look something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="[0-9]*" ng-model="myTel">
<div ng-messages="myForm.myTel.$error">
 <div ng-message="pattern">You can insert only digits here</div>
</div>
```